# find a formula $(2^1 + 1)(2^2 + 1)(2^3 + 1)...(2^n + 1)$

Tags: calculus

I want to find a formula for this but I couldn't find. It's that.

---

$(2^1 + 1)(2^2 + 1)(2^3 + 1)...(2^n + 1)$

---

Is it possible to help me for find answer?

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A028362

Comment: read about q-Pochhammer symbol,in your case $QPochhammer[-2, 2, n - 1]$, i think the short-cuts that are there will help you speed up calculation but will not provide a closed form, may be some approximations

Comment: In a word it is unlikely.

Answer (score 4):

As said a closed form is unlikely to exist. However let $P(n)$ be your product up to $(2^n +1)$ then
$$
\ln(P(n)) = \sum_{i=1}^n \ln(2^i +1) =  \sum_{i=1}^n \ln\left(2^i ( 1 + \frac{1}{2^i}) \right) =  \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\ln(2^i) + \ln(1+\frac{1}{2^i})\right) = \\\sum_{i=1}^n (i\cdot \ln(2)) + \sum_{i=1}^n \ln(1+\frac{1}{2^i}) \overset{(*)}{\approx} \ln(2)\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2^i} = \ln(2)\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + 1 - \frac{1}{2^n}
$$

$(*)$ Since $\ln(1+x) \approx x$ for $x$ near $0$. Actually we have $\ln(1+x) \leq x$.

Then simply take the exponential to get back $P(n)$.

---

You can enhance the approximation used in $(*)$ by considering $\ln(1+x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty (-1)^{i+1} x^i/i$ for $x \in ]-1,1]$.

Continuing from "$\approx$" in the above we have :
$$
\ln(P(n)) = \ln(2) \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^\infty (-1)^{j-1} \frac{(\frac{1}{2^i})^j}{j} = \ln(2) \frac{n(n+1)}{2}+ \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2^{ij}} = \\
\ln(2) \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j}\cdot \frac{1 - 2^{-jn}}{2^j-1}
$$
Now if you take only the sum on $j$ up to $1$ instead of infinity, you'll get the approximation above butyou can make $j$ go further and get better approximations.

Here are some numerical result. The first column is the true value of $P(n)$ for $n = 1...10$. The array on the right are the approximations using the formula above by cutting the sum for $j$ up to $1,2,3,4$.
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & \{3.29744,2.90998,3.03379,2.98676\} \\
 15 & \{16.936,14.4861,15.1813,14.9314\} \\
 135 & \{153.528,130.298,136.64,134.382\} \\
 2295 & \{2614.88,2214.89,2322.88,2284.49\} \\
 75735 & \{86332.2,73090.5,76655.1,75388.1\} \\
 4922775 & \{5.61227\times 10^6,4.75088\times 10^6,4.98258\times 10^6,4.90023\times 10^6\} \\
 635037975 & \{7.24005\times 10^8,6.12863\times 10^8,6.42753\times 10^8,6.32129\times 10^8\} \\
 163204759575 & \{1.86071\times 10^{11},1.57506\times 10^{11},1.65188\times 10^{11},1.62457\times 10^{11}\} \\
 83724041661975 & \{9.54544\times 10^{13},8.08005\times 10^{13},8.47412\times 10^{13},8.33406\times 10^{13}\} \\
 85817142703524375 & \{9.78408\times 10^{16},8.28205\times 10^{16},8.68597\times 10^{16},8.54241\times 10^{16}\} \\
\end{array}